# How to Instantiate ObjectFrame in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I am trying to reach methods and properties of ObjectFrame through vb.net.
But when I declared this as

```
Dim objOLEObject As ObjectFrame
```

and then trying to instantiate it as

```
ObjOLEObject = New ObjectFrame
```

it shows error like:

"**429: Retriveing the COM class factory for component with CLSID {3806e95d-e47c-11-cd-8701-00aa003f0f7} failed due to the following error: 80040154**"

To resolve this we re-installed both MS-Office 2003 and VS-2005, but could not get the solution.

Could anyone suggest me how to declare and use this in vb.net?

Thanks.

Comment: Please correct the title of the question. Someone facing same problem will not be able to reach here unless you phrase it right. Also, the tag vb.net is not enough. I think you should add office interop, ms-access (if I understand your question correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the dll has been registered using regsvr32. Verify by looking in the registry for the CLSID.

Make sure all dependant dll's are available.

I believe this is a class not registered error.

Comment: I have gone through the Register and found ObjectFrameClass is already there. Then what can I do now.

Comment: I'm not sure....can you create the object in VBScript? dim o set o=CreateObject("YouNeed to Put PrgId in here")

I wonder if its a problem with the component or with interop

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Josh is saying, have you checked that all the dependency files are present?

This thread might help.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/88a6ea68-f476-4231-822f-27fabe59f458/